# Difference between Assembly Deployment Target set to "GlobalAssemblyCache" or "WebApplication"

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, web-application, gac

When I view the properties for my SharePoint 2010 project I can see an option of **Assembly Deployment Target** which can be set to either `GlobalAssemblyCache` or `WebApplication`.

1. From [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/89716/20540) I was able to figure out that setting value to `GlobalAssemblyCache` deploys DLL to `C:\Windows\assembly`. For `WebApplication`, it says that it will deploy to `website/bin`. What is the exact path where the `WebApplication` option deploys the solution?
2. From [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/62059/20540) it seems that custom fields cannot be deployed with option of `WebApplication`. They can only be deployed to `GlobalAssemblyCache`. Are there any other restrictions when deploying to `WebApplication`?
3. While developing SP solutions which option should be preferred and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As the name suggests, Assembly deployment Target; specifies where the assembly i.e. dll of the SharePoint will be deployed to. So, in case of `WebApplication` deployment target, the assembly will be loaded in the bin folder represented by the IIS site. For example, the deployment is done to port 80 site. Then the path may look like this `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\bin`. Note that other artifacts of the project will be deployed to their respective places. If there is layout mapped folder in the project which contains some .css, .js, .aspx pages. These will be deployed to the physical layouts folder in the Hive.
2. This question was asked by me. The other restriction are Event receivers, Feature Receivers, workflows, timer jobs. [See this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621468/does-a-sharepoint-eventreceiver-have-to-be-installed-in-the-gac-and-if-so-do-al).
3. The first question which you linked has mentioned some Pros and Cons of each method mainly about recycling of application pools. Personally speaking, almost all the solutions I have worked on have been GAC deployed. An advantage with GAC is that it allows multiple versions of same dll.

Comment: In my case the `bin` folder has not been created yet, probably becasue I haven't deployed any `WebApplication` projects yet. Am I right?

Comment: Well in my case it is there even if I haven't deployed any  `WebApplication` project. But you can give it a try in the dev machine and see what happens.